# cell array remove the leading character in each cell

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array

I have a 27 x 3 cell each cell contains text.

For some annoying reason the data I'm using has been saved with each cell starting with a ', how do I remove these?

Example of my data

```
   column 1    column 2   column 3
   'some       'text      'blah
   'more       'blah      'help
```

What I want

```
   column 1    column 2   column 3
   some       text      blah
   more       blah      help
```

Is the best way to use cellfun? If so how do you use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`cellfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) with a suitable [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). The anonymous function should accept a string and remove its first character, so `@(s) s(2:end)`:

```
c = {'''some' '''text' '''blah';
     '''more' '''blah' '''help'}; %// data
c = cellfun(@(s) s(2:end), c, 'uniformoutput', 0); %// remove first element of
                                                   %// each cell's contents
```

Result:

```
c = 
    'some'    'text'    'blah'
    'more'    'blah'    'help'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html):

```
c = {'''some' '''text' '''blah';
     '''more' '''blah' '''help'}; %// data
c = regexprep(c, '''', '');
```

Which also returns:

```
c = 

    'some'    'text'    'blah'
    'more'    'blah'    'help'
```